# How to restructure query to join tables instead of virtual tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that has two virtual tables joined. Is there a way to restructure this query so that instead of having these tables as virtual tables, I can join them to `requests` as regular tables? I can't figure out how to do that with all of the aggregate functions, etc. contained in them.

```
SELECT
  tr.source_id,
  temp_tri.qty_requested,
  temp_tri.qty_cancelled,
  temp_palletize.qty_palletized_on_time
FROM
  requests r
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      request_id,
      SUM(quantity_requested) qty_requested,
      SUM(quantity_cancelled) qty_cancelled
    FROM
      request_items
    GROUP BY request_id
  ) temp_tri ON temp_tri.request_id = r.request_id
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      tmi.request_id,
      SUM(tmi.quantity) qty_palletized_on_time
    FROM
      manifest_items tmi
    JOIN
      requests tr2 ON tr2.request_id = tmi.request_id
    JOIN
      outbd_containers toc ON toc.manifest_id = tmi.manifest_id
    JOIN
      move_segments ms ON ms.move_to_container_id = (SELECT container_id FROM containers WHERE scannable_id = toc.scannable_id)
    WHERE
      ms.action = 'MOVING'
      AND ms.move_date <= tr2.need_to_ship_by_date
    GROUP BY
      tmi.request_id
  ) temp_palletize ON temp_palletize.request_id = r.request_id
WHERE
  (tr.need_to_receive_by_date BETWEEN (TO_DATE('2011-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2011-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
```

Comment: I think you meant "derived tables" as opposed to "virtual tables." Can you please specify which RDBMS you're using, and what version? In any case, what is your ultimate goal? Do you think performance will be better? It will mean your outer query will have to change because - in order to obtain aggregates on say quantity_requested - you're going to have to add all of the other columns to a single `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I'm using Oracle and the ultimate goal would be to improve performance. This query takes quite a while to execute, and I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way that I couldn't think of. I appreciate your input!

Comment: I don't think the derived tables are the problem, in fact it seems more likely that the schema just isn't designed in such a way that this query will be very efficient (though it is tough to tell without knowing the tables and really reverse engineering this query). Unfortunately I am not an Oracle guy so my best effort would probably not be very helpful.

Comment: If it's a performance issue, what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: There are several references to a table `tr` (`tr.need_to_receive_by_date` and `tr.source_id`).  Are these supposed to be `r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way, if you're using Oracle, is to transform that sql that you use it a lot in a materialized view. In the example below, you have a materialized view based in your fist sql, created with fast refresh.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW aggregated_requests
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS 
SELECT
      request_id,
      SUM(quantity_requested) qty_requested,
      SUM(quantity_cancelled) qty_cancelled
    FROM
      request_items
    GROUP BY request_id;
```

And then you have a physical table instead a query.

Check this out:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can unnest inline views as necessary, so don't bother trying to tidy them up.
Some form of explain plan and description of tables (size, indexes etc) should give more suggestions (but maybe in a separate question).

As Cheran pointed out, you don't show where the 'tr' table/view comes into things.

I'd also focus on this:

```
SELECT
      tmi.request_id,
      SUM(tmi.quantity) qty_palletized_on_time
    FROM  manifest_items tmi
    JOIN  requests tr2 ON tr2.request_id = tmi.request_id
    JOIN  outbd_containers toc ON toc.manifest_id = tmi.manifest_id
    JOIN  move_segments ms ON ms.move_to_container_id = 
          (SELECT container_id FROM containers 
          WHERE scannable_id = toc.scannable_id)
    WHERE ms.action = 'MOVING'
    AND   ms.move_date <= tr2.need_to_ship_by_date
    GROUP BY tmi.request_id
```

and look to a rewrite with EXISTS. I have a general rule that a table shouldn't be in the FROM list unless a column is actually SELECTed.

The join to tr2 - do you have requests in manifest_items not in the requests table ?

```
SELECT tmi.request_id,
      SUM(tmi.quantity) qty_palletized_on_time
FROM  manifest_items tmi
WHERE exists
  (SELECT 1
    FROM  outbd_containers toc
    JOIN  containers c ON c.scannable_id = toc.scannable_id
    JOIN  move_segments ms ON c.container_id = ms.move_to_container_id
    WHERE toc.manifest_id = tmi.manifest_id
    AND   ms.action = 'MOVING'
    AND   ms.move_date <= tr2.need_to_ship_by_date)
 GROUP BY tmi.request_id
```